# Determining $\arg(u-\sqrt{3})$ in exact form.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $u$ be the solution to $z^5=-9\sqrt{3}i$ so that $\frac{\pi}{2}\le arg(u) \le \pi$.

Determine $\arg(u-\sqrt{3})$ in exact form.

How would I go about completing this question?

Comment: What is $cis$? Do you mean $cos$?

Comment: I guess it was just a shortened form. cis(x) = cos(x) + i sin(x).

Comment: I see, ok.  What is the relevance of the first line to the second?

Comment: I added it there just to give more background information regarding the topic and what the topic is. I'll just remove it because it might be confusing.

Comment: For anyone wondering the removed part was: Another solution to the complex equation $z^2=-9\sqrt{3}i$ is $z=\sqrt{3}cis(-\frac{\pi}{10})$.

Comment: Thanks :) It will be difficult to solve $z^5=-9\sqrt3i$. It may be easier to solve $z^{10}=243i$.I take it you are familiar with De Moivre's theorem and Euler's relation?

Comment: @SiS.: you should have left the polar form, to spare us a recomputation.

Comment: @A-levelStudent: "easier to solve $z^5=\cdots$ than $z^{10}=\cdots$": what ?

Comment: Please write it as $-9i\sqrt3$ this is what confused me and led to my wrong method and answer.

Comment: I have corrected and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. We know $-9i\sqrt3=9\sqrt3(\cos-\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin-\frac{\pi}{2} )$
This means (using De Moivre's Theorem)
$$r^{5}(\cos5\theta+i\sin5\theta)=9\sqrt3(\cos-\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin-\frac{\pi}{2})=9\sqrt3(\cos(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$$
So $r^{5}=9\sqrt3$ so $r=\sqrt3$.
We also have $5\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ so $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{2k\pi}{5}$

For different values of $k$:
$$k=0: \theta=-\frac{\pi}{10}$$
$$k=1: \theta=-\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{2\pi}{5}=\frac{3\pi}{10}$$
$$k=-1: \theta=-\frac{\pi}{10}-\frac{2\pi}{5}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$k=2: \theta=-\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{4\pi}{5}=\frac{7\pi}{10}$$
$$k=-2: \theta=-\frac{\pi}{10}-\frac{4\pi}{5}=-\frac{9\pi}{10}$$
Ignore all values of $\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ as this is what you specified. This leaves us with : $$\theta= \frac{7\pi}{10}$$
So (using Euler's relation, that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$:
$$ u=\sqrt3 e^{\frac{7i\pi}{10}} $$

Can you do it from there?
Hope that helped :)

Comment: This is all wrong, starting from the very first line.

Comment: I'm not sure why. What's the mistake?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought the $i$ in the question was in the square root!!

Comment: I have corrected and edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Green points represent solutions of the equation $\;z^5=-9\sqrt{3}i.$

From $|z^5|=(\sqrt3)^5\;$ it follows that $|u|=\sqrt3,\,$ and the points with affices $\;0,u,u-\sqrt3,-\sqrt3\;$ are vertices of a rhombus. Therefore, diagonals are also angle bissectors. We have

$$\arg(u-\sqrt3)=\frac{7\pi}{10}+\beta,$$
where $$\frac{7\pi}{10}+2\beta=\pi.$$
This gives
$$\arg(u-\sqrt3)=\frac{17\pi}{20}.$$

[image]